# get weather forecast for day and night only

Tags: openweathermap

I am hoping to use openweathermap for forecast but on a daily basis (one forecast per day), instead of ever 3-hour per day forecast.

I don't thikn OWM have such an end point but is there away it can be calculated once data is retrieved?